# Hexagons and pentagons on a standard soccer ball

Tags: geometry, polyhedra

How would one go about calculating the diameter of the circumscribing sphere formed when the soccer ball is fully inflated? Suppose, for example, the curved side lengths where all the hexagons and pentagons join on the sphere's surface are 2.5 inches.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Truncated_icosahedron#Cartesian_coordinates

Comment: You have to be slightly more careful. If the edges are measured on the sphere they are longer than assumed in Wikipedia's formulas.

Comment: To the OP: this may seem a bit strange, but: are the polygons regular as planar polygons or regular on the surface of the sphere? The two cases are not identical when you don't have a _platonic_ solid.

Comment: Yes, have to careful - the wiki article talks about chord  lengths, as opposed to the curved side lengths.

Answer (score 1):

From the Wikipedia page on [Truncated Icosahedron](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Truncated_icosahedron#Cartesian_coordinates)

we have the formula

$ r_u = \dfrac{a}{2} \sqrt{1 + 9 \varphi^2 } = \dfrac{a}{4} \sqrt{58 + 18 \sqrt{5}} = 2.47801866 a $

where $r_u$ is the radius of the circumscribing sphere and $a$ is the (straight) edge length of the truncated icosahedron.

Now the angle subtended by the edge at the center is

$ \theta = 2 \sin^{-1} \bigg( \dfrac{ a }{2 r_u } \bigg) = 0.40633789 \text{ 
  (radians)}$

Therefore, the curved edge length is

$ c = r_u (0.40633789) $

i.e.

$ r_u = 2.461006 c $

Now, we're given by $ c = 2.5 \text{  inches} $, therefore,

$ r_u = 2.461006 (2.5) = 6.152515 \text{   inches} $